# sum of digits in different bases

Tags: nt.number-theory, recreational-mathematics, digits

Given a natural number, What is the maximal natural number below it, whose sums of digits in base 10 and base 2 are the same? Is there a clever algorithm to do this aside from the brute force search? http://oeis.org/A037308 is the sequence of those numbers.

Related questions are: Does there always exist a natural number the sum of the digits in the binary and decimal representations of which both equal to a given natural number? Is the maximum of such numbers for the given digit sum finite?

We can see that, in the sequence of natural numbers the binary and decimal representations of which are equal, an even number $n$ appears if and only if the odd number $n+1$ does.

I have posted this question in math.stackexchange.com and have not gotten any answer.

What if the upper bound of the number is given as 1000, instead of a general method, is there a trick to solve it quickly?

Comment: For reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338149/sum-of-digits-in-different-bases

Comment: When posting a problem like this, please compute the first few terms of the sequence and check with the OEIS, so that others don't have to.  In this case you get http://oeis.org/A037308

Comment: @Barry: The question is only remotely related to A037308.

Comment: @Mark, unless I'm mistaken, A037308 is precisely the sequence the OP is asking about.  (I'm not suggesting it answers the OP's questions, just that it's a helpful starting point.)

Comment: I added a specific bound of 1000. Is there a short cut for this ad hoc example?

Comment: For 1000: our maximal $n$ must satisfy $(s_10(n)=) s_2(n) \le 9$. There are only 5 numbers with 9 ones in binary --- none of them works. Then check those numbers whose decimal sum is 8 (800, 710, etc.). None of them work until 503, which is the answer in this case.
Granted, this is still somewhat brute force...

Comment: @Hans, I have extracted a specific case of your related questions and posted it separately at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126286/how-often-do-two-powers-of-2-equal-two-powers-of-10-when-summed

Comment: @Daniel m3: That is in principle what I did for 1000 as well. However, if you have stopped checking at 8 starting from 9, that is wrong, because unless you can prove otherwise, there is no reason to believe the qualified numbers of smaller digit sums do not interleave amongst those of larger digit sums. So you have to check almost all combinations of all sums.

Comment: @Barry Cipra: I will look into your post, later...